# Have just 1 browser tab play alert sound

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I'm trying to have the browser play an alert whenever another guest visits the same page. To do so, an sql query, run every 5 seconds (controlled by jquery/javascript's setTimeout(), selects visitors whose landing time is within the past 5 seconds, and plays an alert as well as show a notification if I get something returned. Working code is here, FYI:

```
select * from visitors where NOW() - landing_time < 5"
```

The problem is that this script runs in every tab I open, so I hear 2 alerts if I have 2 tabs open. What's the workaround so that I only hear the sound once? It's okay that the notification text shows up in both tabs because it's irrelevant, but having 2 alert sounds is misleading, as if 2 users just landed. ding-ding is also annoying!

Comment: Is it good enough to only make the alert sound for the active tab?  I think that is going to be easier.

Comment: Implementing this on the client side, especially if you want a decent level of browser support, carries with it a potential race condition that is unresolvable. In order to implement this in a way that is *guaranteed* to be reliable, you will need to track whether a particular notification has been sent to a particular client on the server side. This has a number of problems - for example you will be storing data on the server that you probably don't want to hang on to, and realistically you will end up using the database to ensure these operations are atomic, which is a sucky design :-(

Comment: @Brad - good point; I forgot to mention that I want the alert if all tabs are inactive too, because the user wants to know that someone's on. I thought about doing this as the second-best solution.

Comment: make it an atomic operation on the server and set a "message has been sent" flag somewhere, so that no matter how many clients/tabs are pounding on your server, only one response would ever get a "you've got mail" notice.